# Script to limit the no. of characters in a textbox not working. Any Ideas?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script which is supposed to limit the no. of characters entered in a text box or textarea. I know I can do this using maxlength attribute. But I want to use JS implementation.

Below is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xTrKD/

CODE:

```
$(function() {
function limitText(limitField, limitNum) 
    { 
        if (limitField.value.length > limitNum)
            { 
                limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);
                }
        }

})​
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="sessionNo" name="sessionNum" onKeyUp="limitText(this,5);" />
```

Comment: your handler never fires. If I was you, I would try using jquery to bind the keyup event to the input

Comment: but why, I am getting limitText() is not defined in firebug

Comment: @TommyBs: sorry I also added html to invoke this/

Comment: yeah I saw in the fiddle. The fiddle in my answer fires. You can test it with a simple alert

Comment: `limitText` is not *visible* for your DOM. You can make it visible by making it globall by changing `function limitText` to `window.limitText = function`.

Answer (score 5):

First off, working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ralt/xTrKD/2/

You had 2 errors:

- The `limitText` function was defined in the `$(function(){})` function, thus not available outside of it. (like, in the HTML.)
- The fiddle was wrongly configured. See the options on the left.

By the way, putting javascript in the HTML is a bad idea. You're mixing the content with the behavior. You'd better separate your concerns, using such kind of solution:

```
$(function() {
    $('input').on('keyup', function() {
        limitText(this, 5);
    });

    function limitText(limitField, limitNum) {
        if (limitField.value.length > limitNum) {
            limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually my fiddle is like this , I dont think jquery is even needed here:http://jsfiddle.net/Y8fEv/

Comment: @Mike and it doesn't work because of the "onLoad" option on the left. See how mine is configured.

Answer (score 2):

[Working fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/xTrKD/10/).

You really don't need a lot of code for this:

```
function limitText(limitField, limitNum) {
    if([8, 37,38,39,40, 46].indexOf(event.which) == -1) // If the currently pressed key is not the backspace(8), arrow keys(37-40), or delete(46);
    return limitField.value.length < limitNum;          // Check the input field's length.
}
```

Keep in mind that I added the a `return` statement in your `input`'s html, and changed the `onKeyUp` to `onKeyDown`.

Returning `false` to a `onKeyDown` prevents the character from being entered. the advantage of this is that you won't have the entered character flash for a moment, before being removed.

The `if` is a exception to make sure the <kbd>backspace</kbd>`(8)`, <kbd>arrow keys</kbd>`(37-40)`, and <kbd>delete</kbd>`(46)` key still work.

That array with numbers are the keys' keycodes. If the currently pressed key (`event.which`) is not one of those, `indexOf()` returns -1, so and the function can check the length.

Comment: woah man after adding five chracters you cannot remove them :P

Comment: Blocking all keydown events when length > 5, also happens to block backspace (and i'm pretty sure, delete).  How do you enter new chars?

Comment: @AspiringAqib: Fixed. cHao: I'd appreciate it if the downvote were removed.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Removed.  But it'd be nice if you explained what that list was for (in particular, what the numbers represent).

Comment: @AspiringAqib: what does indexOf(event.which) == -1  do

Comment: @Cerbrus: No you are the rock star as of now :)

Comment: well @Cerbrus, You Got +2! ;)

Comment: @Cerbrus: keydown: http://jsfiddle.net/67FMq/15/  and keyup http://jsfiddle.net/67FMq/14/. Do you know why my fiddle wont work. IN keydown first keystroke wont fire, and in keypress code doesn't stop after 10 keystrokes. Any Ideas?? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Further on from my comment above

http://jsfiddle.net/xTrKD/1/

```
$(function () {
    $('input').on('keyup', function (e) {
        limitText(this, 5);
    });

    function limitText(limitField, limitNum) {
        if (limitField.value.length > limitNum) {
            limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);
        }
    }
})​;
```

Comment: why can't it be invoked from html

Comment: See @Florian's response below for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You aren't exposing `limitText` to the global namespace. Try assigning it to `window.limitText`, so your event-handler can find it. Or, use jQuery to bind it to keyup from within the closure.

Answer (score 0):

Working fiddle (no jQuery and code in head) http://jsfiddle.net/xTrKD/7/

Input:

```
<input type="text" id="sessionNo" name="sessionNum" onKeyDown="limitText(this,5);" />​
```

Javascript:

```
function limitText(limitField, limitNum) {
    if (limitField.value.length > limitNum) {
        limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);
    } 
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution:

```
<input type="text" id="sessionNo" name="sessionNum" myMaxLength="5" />​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

$('#sessionNo').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if ($(this).val().length >= $(this).attr('myMaxLength'))
        return false;
});
​
```